# CocoaPods import Restkit 0.20.2duplicate/Redefinition compile time errors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit, cocoapods

This is my first time using CocoaPods, and I'm very interested in easily managing restkit installation. Unfortunately, I'm running into the issue listed below - the installation complains about duplicates and redefinition of classes.

**How can I fix cocoapods restkit installation that complains about method redefinitions ?**

```
platform :ios, '6.0'


pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.2'
```

Some of the errors:

[image: Restkit duplicate import]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found a solution described here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/832).

It involves searching the project for #import  and replacing it with #import . The project compiles!

```
//#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
```

In this case the offending file was `RKOperationStateMachine`